# R Regex: find string preceding a matching string

Tags: regex, r

```
x <- "what I want to get is THAT THIS is always following"
```

how to extract the string THAT that always precedes the string 'THIS' in R? THAT is actually a number from 0 to inf with varying decimal seperators, comma or point.

Comment: `\S*(?= THIS )` ? if r supports look-ahead.. not familiar with r.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OP your THIS and THAT are confusing, consider rephrasing OP, is *this* what you're looking for?

```
x <- "what I want to get is THAT THIS is always following"

sub('.* ([^ ]+) THIS .*', '\\1', x)
# [1] "THAT"
```

Comment: Sorry - I mixed things up when rephrasing the OP and didn't notice it before. The wording should now be clear..

Comment: All of the answers work well - however, this was the most intuitive to me. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

`\\S*(?= THIS)` as R does support [positive and negative lookaheads using this syntax](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/regex.html) in `perl` mode, simply add `perl = TRUE` to your function call and you should be golden. If you're not, though, do leave a comment.

First, you'll have to escape the `\S` in R by `\\S`. Then, you can use `regexpr` which'll give you the position (start and end) of the match if any (-1 if no match), with which you can then use `regmatches` to extract that value. That is:

```
regmatches(x, regexpr("\\S*(?= THIS )", x, perl=TRUE))
# [1] "THAT"
```

Comment: +1 for being the only person to bother to explain how your answer works. I think this is most useful to future visitors.

Comment: @SimonO101, you've missed all the drama :).

Comment: +1 - thanks for elaborating the approach with lookahead in R!

Comment: @Arun added the explanation; so he should really be given the credit.

Answer (score 2):

Using `strapplyc` in the [gsubfn](http://gsubfn.googlecode.com) package one can use a relatively simple regular expression:

```
> library(gsubfn)
> strapplyc(x, "(\\S+) THIS", simplify = TRUE)
[1] "THAT"
```